# Is there exists any $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N^2}$ such that this two conditions hold?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Is there exists any $(a,b) \in \mathbb{N^2}$, such that this two conditions hold?

1. $7 \nmid ab(a+b)$
2. $7^7 \mid (a+b)^7-a^7-b^7$

My attempts:

1. if $7 \nmid ab(a+b)$, then $7 \nmid a$ and $7 \nmid b$ and $7 \nmid a+b$ .
2. 

$$(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7=7ab(a^5+3a^4b^2+5a^2b^3+3ab^4+b^5)$$
from (1) we have $gcd(7^6,a)=gcd(7^6,b)=gcd(7^6,a+b)=1$ , then by the condition (2) and gauss's lemma we have $$7^6 \mid a^5+3a^4b^2+5a^2b^3+3ab^4+b^5$$

but i'm stuck, any hint!

Comment: Hint: There exists such integers.

Comment: Why, it's not clear to me!

Comment: Hint:  Fix $b=1$ and look at $(a+1)^7-a-1\equiv 0 \pmod {7^7}$.

Comment: @lulu $-a$ or $-a^7$ ?

Comment: $-a^7$, sorry about that.

Comment: My script found gazillions of them, and, BTW, the results are all divisible by $7^8$, not just by $7^7$.

Comment: Also if you put $\ a=\sum_\limits{i=0}^6a_i7^i\ $, with $\ 0\le a_i\le6\ $, you can try finding $\ a_0$,$\,a_1,\dots, a_6\ $, in that order. For each $\ a_i\ $ you should only need to find the solution of a polynomial equation mod $7$.

Comment: @blamocur what are the smallest solutions ?

Comment: @HiddaWalid 39,16